# One detail view for several UISplitViews

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

I have 3 `UISplitViewController`s with different master views, but they have the same detail view. All of them are connected in Storyboard.

All `UISplitViewController`s are nested in `UITabBarViewController`, so I switch between them via tab bar items.

The problem is, when I switch to another tab (another `UISplitViewController`) detail view disappears, I see only master view and a place for detail view is filled with dark gray (see pic). I don't want to reload detail view after switching, just leave it as is on the right side of the screen.

[image]

I'm not sure what code I need to provide, so if you need any, ask, I'll add it to question.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Cause

My first hypothesis was that the if you share a detail view controller between two distinct `UISplitViewController`s, that correspond to two tabs of a `UITabController`, two separate detail view controllers are created. 
This is confirmed with a test project with this layout:

[image]

`Root View Controller` is a `DetailViewController`. When I put a breakpoint inside `viewDidLoad(_:)`, it gets hit twice and printing shows that two different instances of `DetailViewController` are created:

```
(lldb) po self
<TestTabSplit.DetailTableViewController: 0x7fbd10eb9cd0>

(lldb) po self
<TestTabSplit.DetailTableViewController: 0x7fbd10ebc700>
```

## Solution

Use a shared container view controller as the detail view controller of the two `UISplitViewController`s.

Your new storyboard layout will look like this:

[image]

1. Give your detail view controller (in this case a navigation controller), a Storyboard ID:

[image]

2. Next, in your app delegate, instantiate the detail view controller:

   ```
   // Add a variable to reference from elsewhere.
   var sharedNavigationController: UINavigationController!

   func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
       // Override point for customization after application launch.

       sharedNavigationController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SharedID") as! UINavigationController
       return true
   }
   ```
3. Finally, the container view controller, `ContainerViewController`, is just a subclass of `UIViewController` with the following contents:

   ```
   override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
       super.viewDidAppear(animated)

       let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
       let sharedNavigationController = appDelegate.sharedNavigationController

       addChildViewController(sharedNavigationController)
       sharedNavigationController.view.frame = view.bounds
       view.addSubview(sharedNavigationController.view)
       sharedNavigationController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
   }
   ```

With this setup, you'll find that the same detail view controller instance is share between tabs and modifications in one tab are persisted when you change to a new tab.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you!